# PHP PDF creator without a DB

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I am in the process of creating a Web Form that posts to a PDF Form (an FDF) using PHP without a database/server. The purpose of this is to have the Web Form post directly into the form fields created by Adobe Acrobat. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

$nominee = $_POST['nominee'];
$supervisor = $_POST['supervisor'];

function pdf_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) {

$len = $strlen( $pattern );
$regexp = '';

for ($i = 0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    $regexp .= $pattern[$i];
    if ($i<$len-1) {
        $regexp .= "(\)\-{0,1}[0-9]*\(){0,1}";
    }
}

return ereg_replace ( $regexp, $replacement, $string );
}

if(!$nominee || !$supervisor) {
echo "<h1>Please complete the form.</h1>";

} else {
header('Content-Disposition: filename=cert.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// Open the template
$filename = 'coa.pdf';
$fp = fopen ($filename, 'r');
$output = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

fclose ($fp);

// Input data into the fields
$output = pdf_replace('nominee', $nominee, $output);
$output = pdf_replace('supervisor', $supervisor, $output);

echo $output;
}
?>
```

This is code that I got from a PHP book changed to fit fields from the form. Does anyone know why when the submit button is clicked that it just displays the PHP coding (which is behavior I have never seen before from a PHP file)?? It doesn't seem typical for a PHP file to display the code in the browser.

Comment: Because you're not running this on a web server or the web server is not configured to run PHP.

Comment: "I don't have a PHP interpreter, how do I run this code?" - You get a PHP interpreter..

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was a possibility. I am trying to do a work-around since the "index.html", that contains the Web Form, is on a local drive and not on Web Server. The book I am reading suggested that this can be done statically in the web browser, which is what I am trying to do, but I've never heard of PHP doing that.

Comment: Download an Apache stack. for Windows use WAMP, Mac use MAMP, anything else, XAMPP. Instructions for how to do this are usually at the very beginning of any PHP tutorial..

Comment: @Pamblam I have XAMPP, but the file is going to be transferred to a local (shared) drive where users can access it through a hyperlink on a basic HTML web page.

Intranet Web Page (hyperlink) -> Web Form (index.html equivalent) -> 'Post' Method -> PHP Handler -> PDF